# How to correctly access external storage for large app-private data on multiple versions of Android

Tags: android

I have been struggling with this problem for months on and off and it seems Google are just trying to make it as difficult as possible for everyone by changing how the whole thing works every five minutes and the information online is scattered, incoherent, and self-contradictory. I'm hoping someone here understands this enough to help me out.

I have an app which allows the user to perform offline address checks against a fairly large (~4GB) data source stored on the device itself. This data is technically app-private and should not be accessible to other apps (though this is not a primary concern). Due to the large size of the data, I have consistently avoided using the internal private storage for this which has led me right into the chaos of Android's external storage management. I have read that in Android 4.4 the system changed so that apps could not write to the SD card except in their package specific directories. However, Android did not ever seem to create this directory for me and wouldn't allow my app to create the directory either. I was forced to mount my SD card to my laptop and manually create the package directory! This is not something I can expect the end users to do, so my first question is how/when should the package specific directory be created on the SD card?

Now I am finding out that things have changed again for Android 5, 6, and apparently 7 as well and I am getting very confused. The official documentation talks about using getExternalFilesDirs() to get an array of external storage locations. How then am I to know which one to use? Can my app even access these locations? It seems Android is not very prepared for third-party apps to require large private storage.

I have also read that as of Android 5, I am required to the use the Storage Access Framework to write to the SD card, having the user select the directory to grant the permissions.

This all seems ridiculously unnecessary. All I want to do is allow my app to smoothly - and without much user input (the end users are not expected to have even basic technical knowledge) - read/write about 4GB of private data to somewhere on the device and to have it work on most devices. The way that different manufacturers have different storage options combined with the way Android annoyingly tries to separate us developers from the file system is making this simple task into a nightmare!

How exactly should I be going about this? I would like to support as many devices and Android versions (at least 4.4+) as possible with as little user interaction as possible. I understand that there is now Adopted storage which sounds great for what I'm doing but requires the user to set up the SD card correctly before using the app. Given that this app requires a large amount of storage space to function, we have decided to assume we are only supporting devices with a removable SD card.

Comment: Aside the fact that you want to write 4gigs of data onto the mobile device - Android does support creating dirs/files on the SDCard. The official documents have plenty of information on the topic.

Comment: All storage functions with 'External' in the method name is for external storage or removable media. But you are talking about private data. To keep data private use `getFilesDir()`. Please explain what you really want.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDirs() to get an array of external storage locations. How then am I to know which one to use? ` Your app can use all. Even without requesting any permission. The first location will be external memory. The second the sd card. The third usb otg.

Comment: `Adopted storage which sounds great for what I'm doing but requires the user to set up the SD card correctly before using the app`. No. The user has to do nothing for that. Only allow when a permission is asked. It was before Android 7.0 that the sd card had to be choosed for using Storage Access Framework.

Comment: What I really want in private storage but the data is way too large. Plenty of the devices we wish to support don't have anywhere near 4GB of free space on the internal storage but they do have removable SD cards. So we're trying to use that instead but I am struggling to understand how to access the removable storage in a consistent and straightforward manner. I have read much of the documentation and other articles as well and I'm getting totally different information. Should I be using the SAF or not?

Comment: There is no consistant way if you want to support multiple Android versions. You have to live with that. Of course you should also use SAF when possible as it is clear that Google is about to drop the whole file:// scheme.

Comment: `we have decided to assume we are only supporting devices with a removable SD card.`. That is not a clever decision if you ask me. There are coming more and more devices with so much external memory that there is place for several 4GB files.

Comment: How about checking for each available storage for capability to store 4GB file? Then always use it as storage. Though it didn't address about data privacy.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using this concept to get/create a path string when the sqlite DB is first created. I am sure you do not need the test for is MEDIA_MOUNTED but that said who knows what a end user will do. Code below is in the launch activity.

```
    public void onAvail() {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable) + "/Documents/";
        System.out.println("ALL TRUE ==> " + THE_PATH);

    } else {// if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        THE_PATH = "";
        System.out.println("ALL FALSE ==> "+ THE_PATH);
    }
```

This code is in the DBHelper class
public static final String DB_NAME = THE_PATH +"PassWord";

Due to some of my lack of experience and not seeing anyone use this concept the returned string looks odd to me
    /storage/0905-3E16/Android/data//files/Documents/